Flask API behind Nginx Reverse Proxy: Getting '405 Method Not Allowed' Error over HTTPS [Prophet Model]
I have set up a Flask API behind an Nginx reverse proxy to handle requests over HTTPS. The Flask API works fine over HTTP, but when accessed over HTTPS via the Nginx reverse proxy, I receive a '405 Method Not Allowed' error in Postman. I have verified that the Nginx configuration is correct and that the Flask application can handle POST requests to the specified endpoints. What could be causing this error specifically over HTTPS, and how can I troubleshoot and resolve it?
server {      
    server_name ai.domain.com;      
    root /var/www/html;   
 
    #server_tokens off;   
    index index.html index.htm;        
    location / {         
        # First attempt to server request as file, then         
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.          
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;      
    }
    location /api/predict_sales {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:1000/predict_sales;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_cache off;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                chunked_transfer_encoding off;
                allow all; # Allow all methods (GET, POST, etc.)
    }
    location /api/generate_rules/ {
                allow all; # Allow all methods (GET, POST, etc.)
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/generate_rules;
    }
    location /api/demandprediction/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/demandprediction;
    }
    location /api/predict/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/predict;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ai.iceipts.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ai.iceipts.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = ai.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

      
    server_name ai.iceipts.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

